# How to add product to cart in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, product

I have the list of map of product and i want to add that product to cart page on ontap .

I have the list of map of product and i want to add that product to cart page on ontap .

[This is my map of product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKGnc.jpg)

[This is my favourite button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSVK9.jpg)

I want to add those products in cart page when user tap the favourite button.....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee4Dy.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the screen you want with a simple image???

Comment: I have added the image.....

Answer (score 0):

Use flutter [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package. Call SharedPreferences as async function, to save the data use `setStringList()`

```
saveCartProducts() async{
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 prefs.setStringList("cartProducts", Data);
}
```

To get save data user `getStringList()` function

```
getCartProducts() async {
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 var cartProducts= prefs.getStringList("cartProducts");
 setState(() {
  listItems = cartProducts;
 });
}
```

**Notes:**

1. `setStringList("cartProducts", Data);` - cartProducts is name for to saved data use the same to get data. `Data` is your List<Map<String, dynamic>> variable.
2. `listItems` - use this as a variable to set the data
3. Call `getCartProducts()` in `initState()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the data an object, store the data, and then send the data to the Cart Page.

***data.dart***

```
class Data{
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [
    {
     'img': 'Image1',
     'price': '\$ 120',
     'name':  'Headphone',
     'str': 'str1',
     'category': 'Electronics',
    },
    {
      'img': 'Image2',
      'price': '\$ 150',
      'name':  'Gaming Controller',
      'str': 'str1',
      'category': 'Electronics',
    }
  ];
}
```

After creating a data object in main, when you click the shopping cart icon, the data is saved in a random list.

```
///create Object
Data data = Data();

List<Map<String, dynamic>> cart = [];

ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            if(items.isEmpty){
             return Text('no have items');
            }
            ......
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                   cart.add(data.data[index]);
                 },
              ),
          },
        ),
```

Finally, we send the data to the CartPage.

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CartPage(cartData: cart),))
```

Alternatively, you can use the `Provider` package for more convenient management.